# Using wildcards with SET

Tags: sql-server

Table

```
productName   description

+++++++++++++++++++++++++

OpenIDM       Platform for building enterprise provisioning solutions

OpenDM        Full-featured access management

OpenDJ        Robust LDAP server for Java
```

In the above table when I run below query I get the first two records as expected

```
DECLARE @searchInput varchar
SET @searchInput = 'dm'
SELECT * FROM ForgeRock
WHERE productName like '%DM%'
```

Result
OpenIDM     Platform for building enterprise provisioning solutions
OpenDM      Full-featured access management

But when I run the below query, pattern matching doesn't seem to work properly and I get all the records.

```
DECLARE @searchInput varchar
SET @searchInput = 'dm'
SELECT * FROM ForgeRock
WHERE productName like '%'+@searchInput+'%'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6e9af/8

Comment: **Always** declare the length/precision/scale of your datatypes. **Always**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't declare the size of the varchar string. It default to 1. Do a `SELECT` on the `@searchInput` and see for yourself

```
DECLARE @searchInput varchar
SET @searchInput = 'dm'

SELECT @searchInput
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah like @Lamu and @Squirrel said, you should declare the length of your search string e.g :

```
DECLARE @searchInput varchar(50)
```

Answer (score 0):

When You are declaring a variable without any size os by default it will take as 1.
For Example You have decalre

```
DECLARE @searchInput varchar(10)
SET @searchInput = 'dm'
```

IF Declare without size than it take only d and d is Present in All rows so It is returning all rows.